# If $A$ is similar to $-A^T$, is $A$ similar to an antisymmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$-matrix with entries from some field $F$. Assume also that $A$ is similar to $-A^T$, ie. $PAP^{-1} = -A^T$ for some invertible matrix $P$. (Here $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$.) Does it follow that $A$ is similar to an antisymmetric matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.  Since $A$ is diagonal, it is similar to $A^T$ (trivially), and since $A$ and $-A$ have the same eigenvalues, they are similar.  Thus $A$ is similar to $-A^T$.

However the eigenvalues of a real antisymmetric matrix are [purely imaginary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory), so $A$ is not similar to one of these.

Comment: Nice, this works. Is there an example over the complex numbers? Here if we set $P = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -i & i}$, we have $PAP^{-1} = \pmatrix{0 & i \\ -i & 0} = C$, which satisfies $-C^T = C$.